# Списки, словари, кортежи

Tags: python

столкнулся с такой задачей:
допустим есть такой список:

```
values = [[0,1,2], [0,2,10], [1, 2, 9]]
```

Нужно из этого списка сделать такой словарь:

```
dictionary = {(0,1):2; (0,2):10; (1,2):9}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
values = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 10], [1, 2, 9]]

dictionary = {(x, y): z for x, y, z in values}
print(dictionary)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 10, (1, 2): 9}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @Ivan Рад помочь :) Если ответ помог Вам, Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.

Comment: уже нажал :)
спасибо еще раз